# How do I mount a server directory to a Docker Container with Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to mount a directory in my organization's server (`Y:/some/path`) to a docker container. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
services:

  dagit:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: Y:/some/path
        target: /data
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dagit.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: dagit-container

  dagster:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: Y:/some/path
        target: /data
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Daemon.Dockerfile
    container_name: dagster-container
    tty: true
    env_file: .env
```

I have shared `Y:/some/path` with Docker. On `docker compose up -d --build`, I get the following error: `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /host_mnt/uC/my_ip/some/path`. How can I properly mount such a directory? Also, what would be the correct way to declare this mount in the top level `volumes` key and reference it in both services so I don't have to duplicate the code?

Comment: Which docker-compose version is this?

Comment: `docker-compose version 1.29.0, build 07737305
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.9.0
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020`

Comment: declaring the version in the compose file is optional since v1.27.0

Answer (score 2):

Take the following docker-compose.yml file:

```sh
version: '3.9'

services:
  DockerA:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: DockerA
    command: ["sleep", "300d"]
    volumes:
      - "./data:/root/data"

  DockerB:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: DockerB
    command: [ "sleep", "300d" ]
    volumes:
      - "./data:/root/data"

volumes:
  data:
```

And next to that file (same directory) create a directory called 'data'.

Now start the dockers with:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

If you enter the DockerA container and create something in the data directory:

```sh
docker exec -it DockerA /bin/bash
# cd /root/data
# echo "Hello World!" > x.txt
```

then go into DockerB

```sh
docker exec -it DockerB /bin/bash
# cd /root/data
# cat x.txt
```

you will see the same contents of x.txt.

Now back to the host and check the x.txt file in your ./data directory.
Also same contents.

If you edit x.txt on the Host, it will immediatelly be reflected in both DockerA and DockerB.

Comment: thank you @BertC for illustrating. I somewhat understand all this, my problem is that instead of `./data`, my files are in a remote drive. So my computer has drives C: and D:, and I'm trying to mount a directory in Y: (my organization server). This is what is throwing me an error, as it doesn't seem to find such directory based on the name I provided. I'm thinking of creating a (hard) symlink to work around this, as it would allow me have a local path pointing to the remote data, but not sure if it will work

Comment: The "Y:" suggests you're on Windows. Sorry, I'm OSX-fanboy myself. But you can test by replace "./data" into "Y:/some/path".

Comment: That's what I have in place as shown in my question

Comment: Sorry, then I see that I did not answer your question. You need a Windows guy to help you out further.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your enterprise share is Windows/SAMBA CIFS/SMB-Share, add it as Volume directly and not via Windows mount.

```
volumes:
  shared_folder:
    driver_opts:
      type: cifs
      o: username=smbuser,password=smbpass,uid=UID for mount,gid=gid for mount,vers=3.0,rw
      device: //hostname_or_ip/folder
```

Version depends on your Server Type, rw = readwrite
Then map the volume

```
services:
  dagit:
    volumes:
      - shared_folder:/root/data
```

Comment: Thank you @araisch, I'll give this a go. The credentials in this case would be my regular computer login? What about the UID and GID, am I free to come up with a value? As I understand (after a quick search) this applies to the Linux kernel inside the container

Comment: Normally enterprise shares use AD (so yes, your Login credentials) for managing rights. But can be another user as well. I have the feeling you should talk to the admin of the share about your plans before doing that.. not only because you're going to expose your AD credentials in a plain text file.. He could create a special user with only the rights your app will need. Uid is the user used for mounting, but if you don't need a special user or group just omit both.